# what is causing this cyst on paw of my dog?

Tags: dogs

[image]

Such a cyst appears on my dog's paw, then disappears after a few days and appears on another finger again. Every now and then, he licks it. Is it a serious issue to worry about, or is it common and nothing to worry about?

Comment: A cyst won't go away typically (not permanently at least) without being removed.  It _may drain_, and go back to somewhat normal looking, but if the cyst pocket isn't removed, it will often get re-infected and return.  Does this ever drain out? Or just disappears after some time? The fact that it appears to change "fingers" makes me think its not a cyst but just some sort of rash, possibly caused by allergies and worsened by the dogs licking.

Comment: i have seen a similar wound on a cats paw,it was caused by a tiny rock fragment causing an imune response.i think you should contact your vet to get an x-ray taken.

Comment: I don't know exactly what that is, but it's absolutely not common. It looks like inflammation to me, be it from a foreign body or some underlying inflammatory condition. I would definitely take this animal to a vet.